# how to update a JSON record in ionic by id

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an android application using IONIC that has static JSON users Record data which looks like this:

```
serv.factory('Records', function(){
      var users = [{
        id: 0,
        profilePic: 'img/pic4.jpg',    
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'admin',
        fname: 'first Name',
        lastName: 'Last Name',
        email: 'email@email.com'
      }, {
       id: 1,
       profilePic: 'img/pic3.png',    
       username: 'user',
       password: 'user',
       fname: 'First Name',
       lastName: 'Last Name',
       email: 'email@email.com',
       }];

  return {
    all: function(){
      return users;
    },
    remove: function(user) {
      users.splice(users.indexOf(user), 1);
    },
    get: function(userId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].id === parseInt(userId)) {
          return users[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
```

});

I have a modal view that has input text with the following values on the record above. Now, I am trying to update the record through getting all the values via ng-click="updateUser(user)" and passing the data to controller. My Controller function is this:

```
  $scope.updateUser = function(user){

   $scope.users.push({id : user.id, profilePic: user.profilePic, username: user.username, password: user.password, fname: user.fname, lastName: user.lastName, email: user.email, dob: user.dob});

Records.remove(user);

    $scope.modal.hide(); 

  };
```

this really works because i just created new Array inside users and deleting the other users record where the ID is equal to what i have inserted BUT the record i have inserted changed its position to the bottom of my display list of records.. What i want to know is that, is there anyway(possible way) that i can update the record without messing things up? like when i view the second record it mixed some data to the 1st record :(. I Just want to have an update just like a database query update FROM where ID=ID, just something like that.

I am getting the update from here in my view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Account">
  <ion-content  can-swipe="true">

      <ion-list can-swipe="true">
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'id'" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/account/{{user.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{user.profilePic}}" style="width: 64px; height: 64px">
        <h2>{{user.username}}</h2>
        <p>{{user.password}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

        <ion-option-button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="remove(user)">
          Delete<!-- <i class="icon ion-android-delete"></i> -->
        </ion-option-button>
        <ion-option-button class="button button-positive" ng-click="openModal(user.id)">
         Edit<!-- <i class="icon ion-edit"></i> -->
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

<script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()"><i class="icon ion-android-close"></i></button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content >

    <form name="form" ng-model="form">
      <ion-list>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="user.id">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" value="{{user.username}}">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Current Password</span>
          <input type="password" value="{{user.password}}">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">New Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="user.newPass">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Confirm Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="user.confPass">
        </label>        
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
          <input type="text" value="{{user.fname}}" >
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
          <input type="text" value="{{user.lastName}}" >
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
          <input type="text" value="{{user.email}}" >
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Date of Birth</span>
          <input type="text" value="{{user.dob}}">
        </label>
      </ion-list>
          <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="updateUser(user)">Update</button>
    </form>

    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you doing a partial update or a full, but I will assume you are doing a full update. The other question Is where are you getting the update info from?, for the sake of brevity I'm going to assume that you are getting the info from a outside source either from a form on the page or a ajax call.

You can update the user by looping through the user array and looking for the user with  the same id as the updated info. then simply set that user to the new updated info. This method will replace all info.

Something Like this:

```
$scope.updateUserFull = function(updatetUser){


         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {

             if  ($scope.users[i].id === updatetUser.id) {

                  $scope.users[i] = updatetUser;
             }

         }

         //console.log($scope.users.indexOf(user), user, index);
    };
```

Then to keep everything in order use a orderby filter

```
  ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'id'"
```

If you are trying to update the user array from the list created in the ng-repeat
then you can do this

```
$scope.updateUserFullFromNgRepeat = function(updatedUser, index){

     var idx = index;
     var usr = user;


    $scope.users[idx] = usr;
};
```

And pass the index like this

```
updateUserFull(user,$index)
```

if you trying to a partial update the solution posted by cfprabhu should work

Here is a working plunk demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/rJDKKfdRYJ0NB2iI6PVY?p=preview

v2

http://plnkr.co/edit/ms3QHkxfmJsqxJ6ILMeI?p=preview

Comment: Okay that helped in arranging the view. Thanks, what about the updating part?

Comment: when you say update are inserting a new user into your array of users or are you changing data on an existing user?

Comment: changing data on an existing user

Comment: are you changing part of the data or all of it ?

Comment: also if you could post your view code it would help alot

Comment: Hope this works for you I m about to head out for the day, if it doesnt work out or you have other questions post another comment and ill get back to you on Monday, Cheers

Comment: Actually the update was a choice to the user profile owner, that if he will update his last name then that's a partial and that's what i am doing to check if i have updated it successfully @TimCodes

Comment: I can show you a couple ways of updating the user partially, but it depends on what the data looks , if its a string, object, etc.... if you could provide the part of your  view that updates that updates the user.  I can give you a function to work with

Comment: regarding on how do i update the users info, i also included my view in the above question,that when i click on edit, it opens the modal that carries the user id and bring it to the openModal() function in the controller which has the get() function in my services (as how i presented my services above). Then the retrieved data is displayed in the modal by making it a value in my input types. @TimCodes

Comment: in your form use ng-model = "user.propname" instead of value = "{{user.propname}}", this will give you a two way binding from your scope model too your view

Comment: then you can just have $scope.user property on your controller and use that to update you users

Comment: Here is  a new plunk, should do what your looking for http://plnkr.co/edit/ms3QHkxfmJsqxJ6ILMeI?p=preview                                       Have a good weekend